# multi stage range validation

Tags: javascript, c#, python, asp.net, validation

So I want to have essentially have two range validators, so there is two limits.

Ex. I have a text box that has a range validator of min. 1 and max 10 and if out of that range the value is not accepted but inside that range there is another range validator which is min. 3 and max 6 and if outside that range a messagebox pops up saying your value is out of operating range, do you still want to submit the value? It also needs to be at runtime.

Im not quite sure how to go about this, if anyone can help that would be awesome.

Comment: You can use JavaScript or do it on postback.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at this post. You can use a CustomValidator to do what you need.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251842/asp-net-extended-range-validation